# Formato para moneda (MXN) DataFormatString

Tags: html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy aplicando en el modelo el DataformatString deseo que en el precio de los productos aparezca el costo separado por miles con una (,) y que aparezca sin decimales. Pude hacer que no aparezcan los decimales pero no que aparezcan los miles separados con (,) ya que aparecen separados por (.) y parece que indica centavos en vez de miles.

Model

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:$#,#}")]
 public double Price { get; set; }
```

Html

```
Precio: @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Products.ElementAt(i).Price) MXN
```

APARECE

> Precio: $17.572 MXN

Mi interés es que aparezca de la siguiente manera

> Precio: $17,572 MXN

Antes en el modelo lo ponía de la siguiente manera si mal no recuerdo

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
 public double Price { get; set; }
```

pero me aparecia la moneda en Euros y yo la necesito en moneda Mexicana y que los miles me aparezcan con comas y sin decimales.

Espero me puedan ayudar :).

Comment: podrías agregar la etiqueta<globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es" />  dentro de la sección `system.web` ya que quizá la región de tu sistema este configurada con español  España

Comment: Disculpa, se me paso comentar, si si me sirvio Muchas Gracias, y disculpa el descuido, saludos :)

Comment: Procedo a colocar mi respectiva respuesta  :D

Comment: @ViAAlondra Si la respuesta fue útil, favor de marcarla como aceptada. ✅

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando pones `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]`  toma los datos de la zona en la cual esta configurada tu computadora por la cual me imagino que la tienes con el español de España entonces por eso te sale en Euros  lo que puedes hacer es indicarle al sistema que quieres usar la configuración de México, dentro de tu `web.config` en la sección `system.web` agrega la siguiente etiqueta:

> `<globalization culture="es-MX" uiCulture="es" />`

Así quedara configurado con español México, también te ayudara por si lo publicas en un servidor/hosting de otro país.